# Цитата отдельным абзацем: точка или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, цитата, цитирование

*В резюме избегай цепочек мёртвых существительных, от которых в голове замыкает [ : / . ]*

*«Осуществление контроля за своевременностью выполнения плановых показателей отделом продаж».*

*Ставим живые глаголы и рассказываем то же самое простым языком [ : / . ]*

*«Контролирую, чтобы в отделе продаж планы выполнялись в срок».*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас имеется связь заголовков с перечнями-примерами (пусть даже по одному примеру в перечне), следовательно, нужно двоеточие. (Двоеточие допускается даже без этой связи.) Правда, у Вас связь неявная, а в строгих традициях её следует сделать её явной — добавить "Например:" или каким-то другим способом. Но это не критично, я лучше пройдусь по другим замечаниям.

> В резюме избегай ...
>   Ставим ... и рассказываем ...

Либо "избегаем", либо "ставь... и рассказывай...". Но учтите, что и то и другое звучит ужасно. Рекомендую всюду употреблять нейтрально-уважительное второе лицо: избегайте, ставьте и т.п.

Не знаю, уместно ли будет высказать личное мнение по поводу самого совета. Первый вариант плох, но всё же лучше второго, если речь идёт об ответственном сотруднике (начальнике отдела, например). Второй вариант хорошо бы подошёл для дворника: "слежу, чтоб чисто было во дворе".

Речь идёт об описании в резюме предыдущего опыта работы? Я бы рекомендовал указывать занимаемую должность (напр.: "Руководитель отдела продаж"), а затем объединять в перечне "Задачи и обязанности" пункты вроде: "Контроль выполнения плановых показателей" или "Контроль своевременности ...". Тогда уже понятно, к какому отделу это относится. Можете зайти на сайты, предлагающие работу и посмотреть там требования в вакансиях ведущих компаний либо резюме от тех людей, которых Вы относите к целевой аудитории Вашего сайта (или даже чуть выше).

> б) [ставят] точку, если связь предшествующего перечню текста с самим
>   перечнем ослаблена (нет в этом месте слова или словосочетания,
>   указывающего на то, что дальше последует перечень, перечень прямо не
>   разъясняет этот текст, не служит непосредственным продолжением его).
>
> Напр.:
>   **§33    Однородные приложения разделяются запятыми.
>
>   1. Приложения, подобно определениям, являются однородными, если они характеризуют предмет с одной стороны...
>
>   2. Приложения являются неоднородными, если характеризуют предмет с разных сторон...**
>
> Здесь для двоеточия нет оснований. Хотя точка
>   в таких случаях — знак  не только допустимый, но и предпочтительный,
>   однако замена ее  двоеточием не будет в ряде случаев ошибкой.

Comment: Мой вопрос касается лишь пунктуации, так что стилистические и практические моменты оставим в стороне. "Двоеточие допускается даже без этой связи" — это в каком случае?

Comment: Я дополнил ответ цитатой из Мильчина. Выделенное полужирным и есть пример такого перечня, перед котором предпочтительна точка, но допускается двоеточие. Это не совсем Ваш случай: в Вашем случае я бы предпочёл двоеточие, но с указанием связи между утверждением и примером.

Comment: По поводу пунктуации и стилистики я не соглашусь. Никто из уважающих себя участников не станет отвечать сугубо на заданный вопрос, игнорируя более существенные проблемы. По поводу практических моментов — здесь каждый из нас в своём праве давать и принимать советы :)

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Но ещё один вопрос: где вы увидели перечень? Вроде как просто цитата, приведённая отдельным абзацем.

Comment: Просто в отсутствии контекста и без понимания, что текст будет публиковаться в молодёжном блоге, а не в публицистическом издании или в деловой прессе, исправления таких "более существенных проблем" часто оказываются ошибочными.

Comment: Я понимаю Ваш текст следующим образом. "Такое и такое делать не следует. Например: [здесь отдельным абзацем цитата в качестве примера]". Вот эту цитату я и считаю перечнем из одного пункта. У Вас отсутствует связь между рекомендацией и примером, что стилистически плохо. Если Вы эту связь подразумеваете, то это всё тот же перечень. Если нет, тогда текст лишается смысла.

Comment: *исправления таких "более существенных проблем" часто оказываются ошибочными* — Не хочу спорить. Но я не могу рисковать своей репутацией из-за отсутствия контекста. Я же говорю: Ваше право [зная контекст] не прислушаться.

Comment: Конечно, связь подразумевается (можно поставить слово "например", но оно отсутствует для краткости).

Comment: Да, пусть отсутствует (хотя это лишает Вас шансов найти правило в авторитетном источнике). Но двоеточие хоть как-то компенсирует это отсутствие. В моём понимании двоеточие будет меньшим злом, чем точка.